# Play videos with iframe in html

Tags: html, video, iframe

I want to play a video, but it is only downloading.


Here is my code:

```
<iframe src="videos/1.mp4" width="540" height="310"></iframe>
```

The Result when the page load is:

[image: image when i load page]

How can I play the video with iframe and not with the video tag?

Comment: What is the logic behind this? I can try and play a video inside a `P` tag because I don't want a video element, and it won't work either

Comment: I think what you want is [here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/video). You can, of course, place this under an `iframe` if you want.

Comment: <video> tags not play in older browser

Comment: doesn't ask me to download http://jsbin.com/jolasakine/edit?html,output might be a setting in your browser

Comment: I don't think that lowering the standard of HTML5 because some people still insist of using their prehistoric browser will get you far - It's their own fault and problem. Maybe you can show a message for old browsers and tell them that the need to use modern browser to enjoy the full experience of the website

Comment: You cannot give video source in the IFRAME URL, you have to use the video embed tag. For old browser support you can use polyfill like VideoJS that would use flash player to play in old browsers too

Comment: @neilsimp1 actually it doesn't work when embedded in an iframe https://jsfiddle.net/RachGal/0yrn9owh/3/

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Actually there's nothing wrong with your code!
But the problem is with IDM (Internet Download Manager) as it hooks every link that your browser is requesting and finds whether the destination you're trying to access matches what is in IDM's extensions list, so the first thing would execute after the file being requested is IDM as it has higher priority than your browser and its anyway serving as a listener inside your browser.

you either have to exclude "localhost" from the hook
or you have to remove the mp4 extension from IDM's extension list (which isnt efficient)

Answer (score 14):

Although some browsers might support this way of importing a video(Using an `<iframe>`) some browsers will act towards the video as a file and attempt to download it. The correct way to display a video is using the `<video>` tag:

```
<video width="540" height="310" controls>
  <source src="videos/1.mp4" type="video/mp4">
</video>
```

See W3Schools tutorial here: [video tag simple tutorial](http://www.w3schools.com/tags/tag_video.asp)

Comment: well the original question was without the video tag :-)

Answer (score 3):

Just use the `<video><source src="..." type="video/mp4"></video>` tags.

Answer (score 2):

An iframe tag is used to display another page, not used to play video. You can not play a video with that tag, whether or vimeo youtube or any other company lets you add video using a "iframe" is because they have previously configured some options on that page and have put a video. And that's why you can insert a video through an iframe.

Now if you want to force this, you should do the following:

1. Create a html-and in that html implement a video with the
2. Then from the other page write the `<iframe src = "yourwebcontentvideo.html" />`

And that would be it.

Answer (score 0):

An iframe is an HTML element that allows an external website or webpage or document(like word, pdf) or video to be embedded in an HTML document.

Here is an example for loading an Youtube video through iframe tag on your site

<iframe width="560" height="315" src="https://www.youtube.com/embed/2d2rfsm3ApU" allowfullscreen></iframe>

Output:

```
<pre>
<code>

https://jsfiddle.net/anjaneyulu15/og64djL0/7/

</code>

</pre>
```

Original content is taken from [iframeinhtml.com](https://www.iframeinhtml.com/)

Answer (score 0):

You can use this, you can use the mp4 url as url parameters and return HTML VideoJS player.
https://simplevideoplayer.bubbleapps.io/

Answer (score 0):

You can generate dynamic content like that:

```js
let ifTest = document.getElementById('if-test');
let videoPath = 'https://file-examples.com/storage/fe63ea2155630fa7ba2b829/2017/04/file_example_MP4_480_1_5MG.mp4';
let videoHtml = '<html><body><video width="100%" autoplay="true" loop="true" muted="true" ><source src="' + videoPath + '" type="video/mp4" /></video></body></html>';

ifTest.setAttribute('srcdoc', videoHtml);
ifTest.setAttribute('style', 'width:264px; height:150px;')
```

```html
<iframe id="if-test" srcdoc=""></iframe>
```

Answer (score 0):

Create a new file `(video.php) with the <video src="/vids/video.mp4">` in it.

Then just use the new file in the iframe.

```
<iframe src="/vids/video.php" width="560" height="315"></iframe>
```

and that will work.